# Failed docker images taking up space and I can't locate them (Win 10)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I tried creating a python docker image to use for ML projects, but the image creation failed because the base images were incompatible with some of libraries I was downloading.

I started with 20gb free and after 5 attempts of creating a docker image with different base images, I ran out of memory

These failed images do not come up with the cmd commands "docker images" or with "docker volumes -ls"

I have tried removing them with "docker prune -a". It does nothing

I looked in C/users/me/.docker and the files are not there. I've also looked in program data.

I'VE LOOKED EVERYWHERE, looking at every folder I can see on my C: drive, and I can not find where these failed images/the packages I downloaded are.

I'm completely out of hard drive space now. I don't know what to do next. Does anyone have any ideas?

OS is windows 10.

Comment: did you try rebooting the box ?

Comment: Have you tried to search by `date-range` and `file-size` in your `C` partition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Restarting my computer fixed the problem.